# Kernel#gets attempts to read file instead of standard input

Tags: ruby

I'm rather new to Ruby, and today I wrote an application which you can pass arguments to via ARGV. But inside my application, I want to be able to use "gets". Problem is, every time I try to do so, I get an error.

Here's a simple script which shows my problem:

```
print "Say something! "
input = gets
```

If I'd call that like this:

```
$ ruby script.rb this is arguments
```

I get this error:

```
script.rb:2:in `gets': No such file or directory - this (Errno::ENOENT)
from script.rb:2
```

Hope someone is able to help me solve this, so I can continue my Ruby journey. :)

**Edit:** I am aware that "Gets" won't retrieve arguments passed to the file. "Gets" will query the user for input. I want to be able to use both these methods inside my application.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

If there are arguments, the default `gets` method tries to treat the first one as a file and read from that. To read from `$stdin` in such a situation, you have to use it explicitly:

```
print "Say something! "
input = $stdin.gets
```

Comment: stackoverflow; enabling me to do my job better everyday.

Comment: well that was expected

Comment: then what does gets.chomp do?

Comment: @user2167582: It calls `gets` and then calls the `chomp` method of the string returned by `gets`.

Answer (score 9):

You should be using `STDIN.gets` not `Kernel#gets`.

[Some reference](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M005955).